# Prove there is no function with the following property:

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, functional-equations

I have a function $f:R\rightarrow R$ and I have to prove that there is no $f$ for which $f(f(x))=-2x+1$. First of all I assumed that $f$ is a linear function $f(x)=ax+b$, but I don't think this situation is general enough to prove it's true for any particular cases. I don't know from where I should start. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean no *continuous* function?

Comment: No, it says nothing about the nature of the function. The exercise simply claims to prove that this kind of function where f(f(x))= -2x+1 it doesn't exist.

Comment: According to https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h469717p2629541 on AoPS there are non-continuous solutions.